# DataTemplate is reevaluated on resize of ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I found some unexpected behavior in my WPF program. I have a DataTemplate to visualize my data in an ItemsControl.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding All}"  >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Result:ResultItem/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WPFLibrary:MyPanel Rows="2" MinRows="4" MaxColumns="2"  IsItemsHost="true" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

The strange thing is that the ResultItem view is newly created every time MyPanels MeasureOverride is called and hence calls Measure of its childs.

Is there a way to "force" WPf to reuse the view?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The problem was that every time you create a new ObservableCollection the whole view is updated even if the content is not changed at all.